# Why, Go Figure!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, word-property

> Burnt bridges are crossed. 
>  An icy leg breaks. 
>  The devil speaks in detail. 
>  Rain is pouring over furry pets. 
>  Milk or beans spill. 
>  A missing ship takes sail. 
>  Some system of hands to escape from! 
>  The devil speaks in detail.

There seems to be a storm, but amongst what?

---

**Hint 1:**

> Icy leg = Ice + leg

**Hint 2:**

> If you don't answer this riddle you might just miss the boat and not get the desired $\color{green}{\checkmark}$. But don't cry over spilt milk if that happens! Besides, it hasn't yet, so we'll cross that bridge when we get to it.

**Hint 3 (the last straw):**

> I don't want to beat around the bush, so I am just gonna spit it out: the answer appeared in two forms in this hint, and also in every line in the riddle. This should be more than enough.

So far so good, but I would prefer the answer posted below explains itself a bit more, but lucky it isn't barking up the wrong tree; it doesn't need to go back to the drawing board. (Also, every word in this question is deliberate, but I promise there isn't too much to wrap your head around!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every line ...

> is a mixed reference to two idioms that share at least one word.

Burnt bridges are crossed.

> don't burn bridges, we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

An icy leg breaks.

> Break the ice, break a leg.

The devil speaks in detail.

> The devil is in the details, speak of the devil.

Rain is pouring over furry pets.

> It's raining cats and dogs, when it rains it pours

Milk or beans spill.

> don't cry over spilt milk, spill the beans.

A missing ship takes sail.

> That ship has sailed, don't miss the boat.

Some system of hands to escape from!

> hands off, got out of hand

So the storm is

> causing idioms to mix together like bad metaphors.

Comment: Yes, this was the kind of answer I was looking for! You got the "rain is pouring" part right (there is another, there) but regarding the "system of hands", I was not looking for that answer. Keep trying, though, and hang in there! :P

Comment: @user477343 changed/added guesses for those two.  :-)

Comment: The last one is so close! You got the second part of it right. The first part uses the word "system" in it ;)

Comment: Oh my goodness! It's raining idioms and puzzles @user477343 :) Nice puzzle; nice answer!

Comment: @Brandon_J Don't let the cat out of the bag! ;) I'm kidding, thanks for your comment :P

Comment: Don't worry about that last very minor detail; congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Thanks, @user477343, because that last minor detail still has me completely stumped....

Comment: @Hellion Well, now that you have earnt the big green tick, here is the minor detail: (ROT13) trg bhg bs unaq, **trg bhg bs lbhe flfgrz** :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer speaks for itself (if I may):

> Burnt bridges are crossed. 
>  An ${\color{red}I}$cy leg breaks. 
>  The ${\color{red}D}$evil speaks in detail. 
>  Rain ${\color{red}I}$s pouring over furry pets. 
>  Milk ${\color{red}O}$r beans spill. 
>  A ${\color{red}M}$issing ship takes sail. 
>  Some ${\color{red}S}$ystem of hands to escape from! 
>  The devil speaks in detail.

Comment: Makes sense and certainly fits with the lines of the riddle. But why does the devil line appear twice?

Comment: @hexomino I do have a feeling that there is more to it, but I didn't find more yet.

Comment: @hexomino (ROT13) Lbh pna fnl gung ntnva! :Q

Comment: There was more to it, but not much. You hit the nail on the head! I would mostly prefer that you explain every line, however, so I won't give you the tick yet; but, I don't want to bore you with writing it all in your answer, so you can perhaps reply back in Rot13 if you think you got it, and if you have, I will give you the tick in $24$ hours from then. Good job! :P

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @user477343 I will when I'm back, I just don't have time at all at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: @cwallenpoole have you looked at the hint? If so, would you like en extra hint?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier no problem, take as long as you want! It might work out for the better anyways because the longer this riddle remains unanswered, the more hints I will put up ;)

Comment: @user477343 Thanks so much for the bounty! I'm sorry I didn't have time to explain before others did.

Comment: Hahah, all good! Twice a moderator has commented below a puzzle of mine to inform me of giving a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ if an answer was correct, so I decided to do it once and for all; but there can only be 1, so I decided to provide an additional bounty (namely, this one). I give out bounties very often in situations like this even on other users' questions, so if you gave the right answer but only seconds after another correct answer, and thus you don't get the tick as a result, just message me here and I will give you a bounty depending on how popular or well-viewed the question is :P

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Cats and Dogs? Or Any Ports?

As was previously noted, the following

> Lines all reference idioms in the English language. Plus, @Arnaud Mortier also noticed the IDIOMS acrostic.

Burnt bridges are crossed.

> “Take care not to burn your bridges” means “don’t ruin your connections”.

An icy leg breaks.

> Reference to “break a leg”, means “have a good show”.

The devil speaks in detail.

> The devil’s in the details

Rain is pouring over furry pets.

> It’s raining cats and dogs

Milk or beans spill.

> Don’t cry over spilled milk

A missing ship takes sail.

> All in the same boat

Some system of hands to escape from!

> Hands are tied?

The devil speaks in detail.

> The devil’s in the details

So if there’s a storm amongst something, maybe it could be either

> A big rainstorm, idiomatically represented as “raining cats and dogs”, or maybe it’s amongst “any port in a storm”...?

Comment: No, the answer has already been stated. I just asked for it to explain itself a bit more (because although it does speak for itself, each line isn't really explained, because it's more than just that; so the answer looks like a mere observation, really). If you can explain correctly in your answer, however, I might give you a bounty :)

Comment: Fair enough, @user477343. How does this look?

Comment: Each line is about halfway done ;)